# Github: I did 'git stash -p' after this command, I got the following question; "stash mode change [y,n,q,a,d,?]?

Tags: git, github

I don't know what does that mean... plus actually I wanted to remove all changes

Here are the message I got from the terminal ;

```
(venv) admin@vultr:~/github/easygo$ git stash -p
diff --git a/.gitignore b/.gitignore
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
(1/1) Stash mode change [y,n,q,a,d,?]?
```

What is the next step? what does that mean?

Comment: What do you mean by "remove all changes"?

Comment: I wanted to remove all changes I made on web server or stash them otherwise whenever I  'git pull origin main ' , it crash. that's why I try to do this

Comment: FYI If you don't want to keep the changes for reapplying them later, `git reset origin/main --hard` is probably more appropriate.

Comment: I knew there is better way... thanks. can you explain a little more about the meaning?

Comment: This will reset your local state to the state of `origin/main` removing all changes (`--hard`). Read more in git documentation ;)

Comment: I am lazy to read documentation ^^; thank you so much. today I also learned many... happy~

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: type `q` to quit this mode and rerun without the `-p` option to stash all changes.

---

The `-p` option allow to stash files partially (as opposed to stash the whole file).

When using it, for each identified diff, it will interactively ask if the line(s) need to be included in the stash of not.

See
https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt--p

> Interactively select hunks from the diff between HEAD and the working tree to be stashed. The stash entry is constructed such that its index state is the same as the index state of your repository, and its worktree contains only the changes you selected interactively. The selected changes are then rolled back from your worktree.

And https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt-patch to understand the possible actions at each diff.

```
y - stage this hunk
n - do not stage this hunk
q - quit; do not stage this hunk or any of the remaining ones
a - stage this hunk and all later hunks in the file
d - do not stage this hunk or any of the later hunks in the file
g - select a hunk to go to
/ - search for a hunk matching the given regex
j - leave this hunk undecided, see next undecided hunk
J - leave this hunk undecided, see next hunk
k - leave this hunk undecided, see previous undecided hunk
K - leave this hunk undecided, see previous hunk
s - split the current hunk into smaller hunks
e - manually edit the current hunk
? - print help
```

Comment: Sometimes I forgot to avoid of working directly on the webserver, mostly I do in local server and then push and pull. If there is some changes I made on webserver, then it would crash everytime I try to git pull origin main. Is there any better way or avoid of crashing? If I do remove all the changes, then no problem at all. Thanks again!